# Azure Pipeline .NET Core Build task uses higher MSBuild version than specified in global json SDK

Tags: .net, azure, sdk, msbuild, .net-sdk

I have used "Use .Net Core" task in azure to install SDK using below global json.

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.410",
    "rollForward": "disable",
    "allowPrerelease": false        
  }
}
```

But after that in the next .Net Core - `"Build"` command pipeline task, while building the application, it uses **`MSBuild version 17.7.1 instead using 17.6.8`**.

Earlier it was correctly picking up `MS Build version 17.6.8` and this issue started few days back.

Is there a way to specify **which MSBuild version to use in the .Net Core - "Build" command pipeline task?** **Why is it not picking the correct version related to SDK?**

I have tried specifying the exact SDK version in the `"Use .Net Core"` task as well and specified Compatible `Visual Studio` version as well.

Comment: The global.json only specifies which version of the dotnet SDK to use. It does not specify a msbuild version, or a target runtime version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below `yaml code` to run `MS Build` with `.net version 6.0.410` and the pipeline ran successfully like below:-

**YAML code:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/WebApplication5.sln'  # Update the path to your .sln file if needed

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.410'  
        installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet  

    - powershell: |
        
        dotnet nuget locals all --clear

        
        dotnet --version

        
        dotnet restore ${{variables.solution}}
        dotnet build ${{variables.solution}} --configuration Release
      displayName: 'Restore and Build'

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.0.410'  


    - task: MSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: ${{variables.solution}}
        msbuildArguments: '/p:Configuration=Release'  # Adjust this as needed
        platform: 'Any CPU'  
        logProjectEvents: true
        clean: true  
      displayName: 'Build with MSBuild'

    - powershell: |
        # Run any additional tasks here
        # For example, you can publish your application or run tests
      displayName: 'Run Additional Tasks'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**global.json:-**

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.410",  
    "rollForward": "disable",
    "allowPrerelease": false        
  }
}
```